# How can I set up multiple apache local web sites on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, webserver

How can I set up multiple apache local web sites on Ubuntu?

I added the following to httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/wwwroot/htdocs/firstsite/"
ServerName www.vhostsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I try to go to www.vhostsite.com but browser says he can't find server.

Though, firstsite folder is created in htdocs, and it contains index.html (that is intended to show up in browser)

wwwroot is directory where apache is installed

Comment: Your browser needs to know an IP address, so add the dummy `www.vhostsite.com` to your `/etc/hosts` file, like I wrote.

Comment: Can't this be done without editing hosts file?

Comment: That would require a DNS server. Or registering a true domain, and mapping your server to your public IP address. (But even then some home routers require you to use the `hosts` file, for otherwise the browser cannot connect to that public IP address from within your own network.)

Comment: @Arjan is right, if you want www.vhostsite.com to resolve to localhost you need `hosts` or DNS.  if you run DD-WRT/OpenWRT on your home router you may be able to tweak it to add your own DNS settings there; `hosts` is easier tho.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser needs to know an IP address, while the server then needs more details as for which site to serve. So, to host multiple sites on `localhost` you cannot serve all of them at `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`. Instead:

- Use subfolders, like `http://localhost/site1/`
- Or: set up dummy domains in your [`/etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file (name-based [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting); the browser will connect to an IP address that is used for multiple sites, and then specify the requested host in the HTTP headers):

  ```
  127.0.0.1 www.vhostsite.com
  ```
- Or: rely on some nice [third-party DNS name settings](http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=lvho.st&type=1&server=ns1.nic.st&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000), which of course might change in the future:

  - http://lvho.st and even http://whatever.you.want.lvho.st (where `lvho.st` probably means "local virtual host")
  - http://lvh.me or http://whatever.you.want.lvh.me
- Or: use multiple ports, like `http://localhost:8080` and `http://localhost:8081` (port-based virtual hosting)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [rapache](https://launchpad.net/rapache) to have a GUI to setup your domains instead of editing the config by hand.